# What does -q, -f, -c symbols mean in cron command?

Tags: php, linux, unix, cron

I want to run PHP script via Cron Jobs. So, I read some tutorials and mentioned that there is some difference between commands. So, these commands are these:

1. `php myscript.php`
2. `php -q myscript.php`
3. `php -c myscript.php`
4. `php -f myscript.php`

**The question is:**

What does these `-q`, `-c`, `-f` symbols mean ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: If you want to know what options are available/what they do for *any* command line app, it's a fairly safe bet that the `--help` option will give you a clue. For example, `php --help`

Comment: From [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) as @Aziz suggested:

`-c  --php-ini`

Specifies either a directory in which to look for php.ini. If this option is not specified, php.ini is searched for in the default locations. 

`-q  --no-header`

Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output.

`-f  --file`

Parse and execute the specified file. The -f is optional and may be omitted - providing just the filename to execute is sufficient.